# Redirecting http://example.com to http:/www.example.com while keeping http://subdomain.example.com access intact

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

I have a website on which I've enabled subdomain access such as:

```
 http://subdomain1.example.com
```

which accesses the same code, but passing a domain parameter in order to show a different microsite. The httpd.conf code for that looks like this:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^./]+)\.example\.com$
 RewriteRule forums.html$ /browse.php?type=forums&domain=%1 [QSA]
```

Now I need to redirect http://example.com to http://www.example.com

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-redirect-domaincom-to-wwwdomaincom/ )

EDIT1

```
<VirtualHost IPADDRESS:80>
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/abc
    ServerName www.example.com
    UseCanonicalName On
```

EDIT2

Hi mreithub,

The setup I need is something like this:

http://X1.example.com should use the code in /something/X1

http://X2.example.com should use the code in /something/X2

http://example.com should redirect to http://www.example.com

http://www.example.com/scriptA.php should use the code in /var/www/html/abc/scriptA.php

http://whateverelse.example.com/scriptA.php should use the code in /var/www/html/abc/scriptA.php but be passed with a 'domain=whateverelse' parameter (but the URL on screen should show always show the domain as being http://whateverelse.example.com )

I had asked a question on SF - https://serverfault.com/questions/408805/configuring-httpd-conf-to-handle-wildcard-domains-with-multiple-scripts - from where I used adaptr's technique to pass the domain parameter to the PHP scripts.

Comment: Do you use the apache configuration files or .htaccess?

Comment: The apache configuration files (httpd.conf)

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite for redirecting whole VirtualHosts in apache is to simply create a VirtualHost for the domain to redirect and use the `Redirect` directive:

```
<VirtualHost IPADDRESS:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect / http://www.example.com/
  DocumentRoot /var/www # <-- Just for completeness
</VirtualHost>
```

... and then another VirtualHost for your actual website

`Redirect` redirects every request going to host a to b while keeping any postfixes (e.g. `http://example.com/foo?bar=bak` becomes `http://www.example.com/foo?bar=bak`).

I use `Redirect` a lot to rewrite from http:// to https://

Comment: @Steve I edited the answer to give a more complete example. Hope it helps

Comment: Hi M - please see my Edit1 - which describes what I currently have. That allows access of 'sites' such as 'xyz.example.com' (which I need to have).

Comment: @Steve Just add another VirtualHost like the one I posted. You might need to put them in the right order but it should work. If it doesn't, make sure you've got a NameVirtualHost IPADDRESS:80 somewhere in apache's configuration

Comment: Thanks mreithub - can you have a look at my Edit2 - that fully explains the whole breadth of what I need to do. (a) I have subdomains I don't want 'part of' the subdomain.example.com setup and (b) I need access of subdomain.example.com to be handled with existing scripts via a domain parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. 3 hours later... Lots of changes, lots of learnings.

1) Changed this:

```
   NameVirtualHost IPADDRESS:80
```

To:

```
   NameVirtualHost *:80
```

2) Marked all:

```
   <VirtualHost IPADDRESS:80>
```

As:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
```

3) Rearranged ServerName and placed it first within the VirtualHost (not sure if this made any difference)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test4.example.com
    ServerAlias test4.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/test4/public_html
    UseCanonicalName On
</VirtualHost>
```

3) Rearranged all VirtualHosts. Placed the 'static' / fixed subdomains earlier and the catch-all / www one as the last one. The last one looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/abc
    UseCanonicalName On
    ...
```