# Real subdomains with Godaddy

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, lamp

My .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^deathga.me$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://deathga.me/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

It correctly redirects from www.deathga.me to deathga.me, which solves many things. But it also redirects play.deathga.me to deathga.me/play/ , which is undesirable.

My question is basically the opposite to this: [Redirecting http://example.com to http:/www.example.com while keeping http://subdomain.example.com access intact](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13280811/938236). Only I cannot figure out how to apply it to my site, even looking at that question, googling and trying many things. The question itself is pretty simple: **how to redirect www.example.com to example.com but keep sub.example.com in that subdirectory?** I am not even sure if it's a problem with Godaddy or with htaccess... where should I start looking into? This is a screenshot of Godaddy subdomain configuration:

[image: view of the subdomain]

EDIT: Full .htaccess now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^play.deathga.me$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^deathga.me$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://deathga.me/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: for debugging
1) is the .htaccess is read by the webserver? (make syntax error for example)
2) is the subdomain uses this .htaccess? (make a simple rewrite rule for example: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^play.deathga.me$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://google.com [L]

Comment: Yes, it is being read, it has another condition, making `deathga.me/whatever` act as `deathga.me/index.php?url=whatever` internally, which works correctly. Updated with full .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently what I wanted to do cannot be done with the 'fake' godaddy subdomain and an Economy account: [Setting up a "real" subdomain with Go Daddy](http://blog.chipotoole.com/2010/04/setting-up-real-subdomain-with-go-daddy.html) .

Thank you @borazslo for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^play.deathga.me$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^deathga.me$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://deathga.me/$1 [L,R=301] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That was fine... I actually want the site without `www`, the problem is that it also deletes the `play` bit in `play.deathga.me`

Comment: It still redirects `http://play.deathga.me/` to `http://deathga.me/play/` with the new condition... could it be a Godaddy issue?

Comment: Well. What's wrong with it. You asked to 1) redirect every http://deathga.me to http://www.deathga.me BUT not the subdomains. OR http://play.deathga.me should be redirected to http://www.deathga.me/play?

Comment: No, it should not be redirected. It is being redirected (that's why I asked the question) and I cannot stop it from redirecting, even with your solution...

Comment: So the main question is not about www or not www, but how and where to redirect/link a subdomain. Do you want to use scripts in the /play/ folder as play.deathge.me? In this case the situtation is not so bad, only in the url we should "hide" the redirection. (You should find some lines in the .htaccess about the play.deathge.me)

Comment: Exactly. So there's no way to just have `play.deathga.me` and I should have it as a subfolder and then make it look like a subdomain with .htaccess? Then why would godaddy offer me to create a subdomain, if it's the same?

Comment: OK. I think Godaddy has made a rewrite condition about the play.deathge.me. You should change something in these line. Can you show these lines?

Comment: I cannot find any more lines than showed (in either of the folders) nor in .htaccess nor in php.ini, where should I look for it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32653/discussion-between-borazslo-and-frank-presencia-fandos)